# Figure out right types - Typescript interface method overload

Tags: typescript, overloading, typescript-generics, either

I'm trying to figure out how to implement an auxiliary .flatMap method on Either monad. Unlike regular .flatMap it accepts a lambda that returns some regular value instead of Either instance. It's supposed to work like an adaptor to consume functions that were not designed for use with Either.

In the example below I named this adaptor method .flatmap. Can anyone suggest how I can convert that function into a legit Typescript overload of the regular .flatMap?

```
interface Either<TResult, TError> {

  flatmap<R>(f: (value: TResult) => R): Either<R, void | TError>;

  flatMap<R, E>(f: (value: TResult) => Either<R, E>): Either<R, E | TError>;
}

class Left<TResult, TError extends { type: any }> implements Either<TResult, TError> {

  public constructor(private readonly error: TError) {}

  public flatmap<R>(f: (value: TResult) => R): Either<R, void | TError> {
    return this.flatMap(n => new Left(this.error));
  }

  public flatMap<R, E>(f: (value: TResult) => Either<R, E>): Either<R, E | TError> {
    return new Left(this.error);
  }
}

class Right<TResult, TError> implements Either<TResult, TError> {

  public constructor(private readonly value: TResult) { }

  public flatmap<R>(f: (value: TResult) => R): Either<R, void | TError> {

    return new Right(f(this.value));
  }

  public flatMap<R, E>(f: (value: TResult) => Either<R, E>): Either<R, E | TError> {

      return f(this.value);
  }
}

class ResourceError {
  type = "ResourceError" as const

  public constructor(public readonly resourceId: number) {}
}

class ObjectNotFound { 
  type = "ObjectNotFound" as const

  public constructor(public readonly msg: string, public readonly timestamp: string) { }
}

class DivisionByZero {
  type = "DivisionByZero" as const
}

function f1(s: string): Either<number, DivisionByZero> {
  return new Right(+s);
}

function f2(n: number): Either<number, ResourceError> {
  return new Right(n + 1);
}

function f3(n: number): Either<string, ObjectNotFound> {
  return new Right(n.toString());
}

function f5(n: number): number {
  return n * 10;
}

function f6(s: string): string {
  return s + '!';
}

const c = f1('345')
  .flatMap(n => f2(n))
  .flatmap(n => f5(n))
  .flatMap(n => f3(n))
  .flatmap(n => f6(n));

console.log(c);
```

**UPDATE:** For curious, more 'encapsulated' api + statically checked pattern matching:

```
type UnionOfNames<TUnion> = TUnion extends { type: any } ? TUnion["type"] : never

type UnionToMap<TUnion> = {
  [NAME in UnionOfNames<TUnion>]: TUnion extends { type: NAME } ? TUnion : never
}

type Pattern<TResult, TMap> = {
  [NAME in keyof TMap]: (value: TMap[NAME]) => TResult
}

type Matcher<TUnion, TResult> = Pattern<TResult, UnionToMap<TUnion>>;

interface Either<TResult, TError> {

  flatMap<R, E>(f: (value: TResult) => Either<R, E>): Either<R, E | TError>;

  flatMap<R>(f: (value: TResult) => R): Either<R, void | TError>;

  match<R>(success: (result: TResult) => R, error: Matcher<TError, R>): R;
}

abstract class Either<TResult, TError> {

  public static Right<TResult>(value: TResult): Either<TResult, never> {

    return new Either.rightClass(
      value,
      x => x instanceof Either.leftClass || x instanceof Either.rightClass,
      Either.Right
    );
  }

  public static Left<TError extends { type: any }>(error: TError): Either<never, TError> {

    return new Either.leftClass(error);
  }

  private static readonly leftClass =
    class <TResult, TError extends { type: any }> implements Either<TResult, TError> {

      public constructor(private readonly error: TError) { }

      public flatMap<R, E>(f: (value: TResult) => Either<R, E>): Either<R, E | TError>;
      public flatMap<R>(f: (value: TResult) => R): Either<R, void | TError>;
      public flatMap(f: (value: TResult) => any) {

        return this;
      }

      public match<R>(success: (result: TResult) => R, error: Matcher<TError, R>): R {

        return (error as any)[this.error.type](this.error);
      }
    };

  private static readonly rightClass =
    class <TResult, TError> implements Either<TResult, TError> {

      public constructor(
        private readonly value: TResult,
        private readonly isEitherInst: (x: any) => boolean,
        private readonly rightFactory: <R>(result: R) => Either<R, TError>
      ) { }

      public flatMap<R, E>(f: (value: TResult) => Either<R, E>): Either<R, E | TError>;
      public flatMap<R>(f: (value: TResult) => R): Either<R, void | TError>;
      public flatMap(f: (value: TResult) => any) {

        const result = f(this.value);

        return this.isEitherInst(result) ? result : this.rightFactory(result);
      }

      public match<R>(success: (result: TResult) => R, error: Matcher<TError, R>): R {

        return success(this.value);
      }
    }
}

class ResourceError {
  type = "ResourceError" as const

  public constructor(public readonly resourceId: number) { }
}

class ObjectNotFound {
  type = "ObjectNotFound" as const

  public constructor(public readonly msg: string, public readonly timestamp: string) { }
}

class DivisionByZero {
  type = "DivisionByZero" as const
}

class NetworkError {
  type = "NetworkError" as const

  public constructor(public readonly address: string) {}
}

class GenericError {
  type = "GenericError" as const

  public constructor(public readonly exception: Error) {}
}

function f1(s: string): Either<number, DivisionByZero> {
  console.log('f1()');
  return Either.Right(+s);
}

function f2(n: number): Either<number, ResourceError> {
  console.log('f2()');
  return Either.Right(n + 1);
}

function f3(n: number): Either<string, ObjectNotFound> {
  console.log('f3()');
  return Either.Right(n.toString());
  //return Either.Left(new ObjectNotFound('not found ', Date.now().toString()));
}

function f4(s: string): number { 
  console.log('f4()');
  return +s * 10;
}

function f5(s: number): Either<string, ResourceError> {
  console.log('f5()');
  return Either.Right(s.toString() + '!');
}

const c = f1('345')
  .flatMap(f2)
  .flatMap(f3)
  .flatMap(f4)
  .flatMap(f5);


const r = c.match(
  (result: any) => result.toString(),
  {
    //GenericError: (value: GenericError) => value.exception.message,
    ObjectNotFound: (value: ObjectNotFound) => value.msg + value.timestamp,
    ResourceError: (value: ResourceError) => 'resourceError',
    DivisionByZero: (value: DivisionByZero) => 'divisionByZero',
  }
);

console.log(r);
```

[Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=79&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKLDAC2gHgCoBKEAzgK4A2YANMnqlFAPZQB8yA3gLABQPyyMcnDABbOAAccBFgAoYALmQyAbnHKkIiwiQpgAlMgC8bAnsXosuAjWWNgAE2QAfWvSasA3Dz4ChYALISUjSosgpKquqatERklAbGaBjYUMFoLGZJlqnWaM6uDMwsXtwAvt7cCELExMgAMhAwYPixujR0hVDIEAAekCD2tezIYACe4tFwIKPIpWzAIuLkECIQ4LUWKS06lO1uRRwV-OKkAEbkwAjICIwgxGBQpAhgzDLiUMCqkMhQEHD2t3IM2g7i0%20ygBnY5V43GOZwuV0EwjEkmkckUKjUGi0rXiRhMmU2VhsdkcLg67jYXFh-B%20EDApCgIBGmGAxAAdEiAhIZMzEiAIAB3eqNMAyLBs9kg5h6PQlfjQnwnc6XXzCQKokJhDGRbExHb6fFZLa5UKE5LEvLk8FUnz8X4MpnIAXChpNcWsjnSiHy2Y8RWVaq1AjAADmmGa2ji1AKlOQCyWKzWYA2FtSUbasYO1KV8NVNzuDyeLygbw%20XxQv3%20gJmuuiGbxwwDcJViL8KKk2oiWPruMNiVM5jTaVsDnyFOzR1pDsZzJdyBD4bFMA9krrst90OQudbau5mvS6O7URxBoSbCJOS15uyaVQ45thxhtOn9NnAlXHPXm-9FSqcBqBcSEYRkkHBJ9%20DGCYjGQAAiWIQKgMDOlg5AAOuW57inZUEQwwtHmeV4cNVKsARAIE6WIRCkAASXsRQQFIERTmgSFoQDf9AIAeVOAArCBngAOUYMAADEQIGDhtxpKCUEMOCeP4oSRPE0gBlQ9CCyw59kGIq4tKLQjSz0ulq3ImYRGIUNFHuD4QFDGgTNImsRgWEgwDgRYbIeUBQ0hP0yj-INkAAEU%20NlgFuAAhUYAC1oEYCCRnGOS4LC5QIuiuKEo02oDN-GEYDU55IuZGAAEYZGIby7L8odb0Y5joBodLMpAGL4qYW0aRnJ150XCMZAAamIOUCp4IqQBK24BAAJl5BimJYiF6q2RrlpoBDQIgR9qXtN8%20qFBcw0G5khuQcqxsCwrirAUqBAAZgW50ltY1bcFs3yaEUgSwGEsSJPsbr9sdOcjoGsUQHZF4AGUfPsmQN3G7hJumsqAFZnvWt6Xqaro9rpUHnWQAAqC6AAYSgDVG7pmmAADYqpq3zMk%20%20ykt65lanOgByABCHmqb-TCwGuGCKpkHmHoAFnRnm9B8Tk-A1XkjRgeaQFlRWuRRVXEhgTHNYVmklfVHk%20TYGAnqN7X23NtXGaNkoeC0xhlnZchGFDGQECuoA) to the playground. Usage of the overload - lines #74 & #76

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [overload](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads) call signatures should be in the order from most restrictive to least restrictive, so probably I'd do it this way:

```
interface Either<TResult, TError> {
  flatMap<R, E>(f: (value: TResult) => Either<R, E>): Either<R, E | TError>;
  flatMap<R>(f: (value: TResult) => R): Either<R, void | TError>;
}
```

Since any `f` of type `(value: TResult) => Either<R, E>` will *also* be a value of type `(value: TResult) => R` (for a different `R`), but the reverse is not true, we have to do it this way.  If we flipped the order then no call would ever be seen as the `=> Either<R, E>` call signature because it always match the more general `=> R` signature.

---

Implementing overloads requires a single implementation signature (since at runtime there will be only one function), so you need to write runtime code to figure out what to do at runtime when handed different types of `f`.

Your `Left` implmentation seems to be completely independent of `f`, so that's an easy one to implement:

```
class Left<TResult, TError extends { type: any }> implements Either<TResult, TError> {

  public constructor(private readonly error: TError) { }

  public flatMap<R, E>(f: (value: TResult) => Either<R, E>): Either<R, E | TError>;
  public flatMap<R>(f: (value: TResult) => R): Either<R, void | TError>;
  public flatMap(f: (value: TResult) => any) {
    return new Left(this.error);
  }
}
```

As for the `Right` implementation, we need to determine if `f(this.value)` constitutes an `Either` at runtime or not.  Assuming only `Left` and `Right` classes implement `Either`, I'd do it this way:

```
class Right<TResult, TError> implements Either<TResult, TError> {

  public constructor(private readonly value: TResult) { }
  public flatMap<R, E>(f: (value: TResult) => Either<R, E>): Either<R, E | TError>;
  public flatMap<R>(f: (value: TResult) => R): Either<R, void | TError>;
  public flatMap(f: (value: TResult) => any) {
    const ret = f(this.value);
    return ret instanceof Left || ret instanceof Right ? ret : new Right(ret);
  }
}
```

And this seems to behave properly on your example code:

```
const c = f1('345').flatMap(f2).flatMap(f5).flatMap(f3).flatMap(f6);
console.log(c); // Object { value: "3460!" }
```

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKLDAC2gHgCoBKEAzgK4A2YANMnqlFAPZQB8yA3gLABQyyM5OGACycAA44CNVCwAUMAFzJZANzjlSEJYRIUwASmQBeNuiy4paFvqVnsUSdOQAfWvSasA3Dz4ChoiQI5RWU1DS1aIjJKQxNkAhs0DHtHZBVGYAATFzcGZhZvbgBfHh4EQWJiZAAZCBgwfCi9Gjo8qGQIAA9IEEyq9mQwAE8xCLgQIeQitmAAWzFyCFmIcCq7XB1o6lyPNi5uH2QxUgAjcmAEZARGEGIwKFIEMGZZMShgNUhkKAg4TJvyJNoB5tO5mIYBiUDrwjqdzpc-CJxKkZPIlKp1JptE0YsZTMkLNJrLYCQ5LKgcq1doU+Mczhd+IIkYFguiwljIrpcXEEiTzGSaOkspSwV5DnT4Yz-OI0aFMRFNnpYmxxkMIYc+D8wKQoCBkCAIAB3Gp1MCyLDAYgAOmB4JpUx4ULKFSqBGAAHNMA1FZQWqKZvNFstVkl+Y0udsqfkOKUYRKGddbvdHs8oK93p8UD8-gDJuyFTiDBwHXG4QzEQEUay5eFsRHlaGUuTiY3CWgRW0CuKywimZWgrKMbXOVsG7zWwK0hlsq4o2LS-Te9KxIP83XR3jkKr1TC+Im7t8IGBjPxzZhLVb8-p7Zqjzq9VrkKA7uMkIwYCb6i5XI-n2BXxA77xB6XrIAA-Iex5KAaxpup6ZpatehxQk63DlHAlTxCQjA6kgooxjCwyjCeABEUQ4VAeFtCRW5VPuYCxrSPZXDcdwPE8Lzxpc2b-CAgKHsQFFIAAkpk0GkLMJzQBCJaoehmEAPInAAVhATwAHKMGAABiOG9ARfBESgRjICRSmqRpWm6aQvQ0RhLFJoxsKLg5bEppxzE8bmyCzMQ7pKGxoDujQXGHjmfGTGAcwkP+8wBfcQUyShsbyVUAAiHyWsANwAEJDAAWtAjAGYMIzGaZGUqFluUFUVdl0axDHFLGMA2U82V6jAACMsjEPF7wgO6iTrA4IASVJUA0JV1UgHlhVMHshxave+pGsB8GyAA1MQSHNdCrUgO1Nz8AATLIIDiZJ0l8ikY1XZNWGCbhED+iVy26qtsEgWaeqbcgXW7ahB1HZ1ADM52XRNw2kjggWDTQ5lqWAmk6XpmSLTC716jB61eudVrPAAyglg2yPogMtW1UXHTAACsEP6uN12M-dxZLXeH16gAVP9AAMhRA1THX8AAbL1-WJRLg1vRzepVH9ADkACECsCyljVXCe3WyAroMACy0wr+hWhWMowCdxumyudOW32Zug7by7yCLu37owixWuQjDurICDXsgAD0AfIIjTzFmupn6yLvNKzRUJAA)

Comment: Thank you very much! Obviously there was a lot of language design trade-offs in favor of certain design choices/goals (e.g. TS compiled code looking like more or less handwritten JS, etc). Overload obviously fell victim of such a trade-off)